# 301 redirect when trying to access AWS Mumbai S3 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket in Asia Pacific (Mumbai) region and another bucket in Singapore region. I set the keys as environment variables. Then ran the following commands in Spark shell.

For Singapore:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com")
val testdf = sqlContext.read.csv("s3a://dev-singapore/test.csv")
```

It ran fine.

For Mumbai:

```
sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3a.endpoint","s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com")
val testdf = sqlContext.read.csv("s3a://dev-mumbai/test.csv")
```

But it gave me following error

```
17/05/31 11:56:58 WARN DataSource: Error while looking for metadata directory.
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Status Code: 301, AWS Service: Amazon S3, AWS Request ID: BDFC*****9C820, AWS Error Code: null, AWS Error Message: Moved Permanently
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:798)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:421)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
```

---

Mumbai region S3 server only supports Signature Version 4 while Singapore supports both Version 2 and 4.

I used Spark (2.0.0) from the docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/stvdberghe/spark-s3/

Answer (score 0):

A 301 generally means that the endpoint you've chosen isn't the one the bucket is actually on.

Try to set the endpoint when setting up the spark context, not later on, either in spark-default.conf or in sparkConf.set("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", ...)

Comment: But the endpoint is correct. I updated the aws-java-sdk to 1.7.4 and now it gives 400. The other endpoint and bucket work just fine.
hadoop-aws jar is of version 2.7

Answer (score 0):

After lot of tries and research, I could find out the problem. Let’s revisit my journey.

Hadoop 2.8 was working with Mumbai s3a. Spark 2.1.1 with Hadoop 2.7 was not working. Spark depends upon Hadoop aws library to connect to S3. So, I figured out that Hadoop was the culprit. Then I looked for Spark with Hadoop 2.8 distribution but it was not available. I tried to replace the Hadoop libraries of Spark-2.1.1-hadoop-2.7 but it did not quite fit.
AWS had changed many APIs and even Hadoop has changed the client libraries to connect to S3/AWS services. It has merged hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk; added aws-java-sdk-s3 and some more libraries.
At last, I built the Spark with Hadoop 2.8 (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/building-spark.html#specifying-the-hadoop-version). It finally worked.

Though I got some errors of Classnotfound

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem
```

so I downloaded the following (because mentioned here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current3/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Dependencies in s3a dependencies) from mvn repository website

- aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.6.jar
- aws-java-sdk-kms-1.10.6.jar
- aws-java-sdk-s3-1.10.6.jar
- hadoop-aws-2.8.0.jar

For the exact version, I looked in the Hadoop 2.8 libs ($HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/) folder. After this, I got joda class

```
org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat
```

not found error which I solved by downloading the joda-time-2.8.2 jar file from the mvn repository website.

Comment: OK, sounds like you've fixed it. I'd have expected the 2.7 JARs (specifically the AWS 1.7.4 client to work with mumbai once joda time was up to date). You could just try updating joda time to 2.8.2 & staying with the 2.7.x JARs. Otherwise: new Hadoop 2.8.x binaries ship in June 2017; spark 2.3 has a build profile "hadoop-cloud" to include everything needed to talk to AWS, Azure and openstack

Comment: @SteveLoughran Thanks for the insight. The Spark distribution, I had, already contained joda-time-2.9.3.jar. I will check hadoop-cloud.

Comment: @SteveLoughran When I compiled latest code of Spark, it did not compile hadoop-cloud. Tried to build it manually but gave error of missing config file.  Is there something to consider here?

Comment: Maven profile I used this morning: -Pyarn,hadoop-2.7,hadoop-cloud  . If that doesn't work, file a JIRA on issues.apache.org

Comment: I could build it. With Hadoop-2.7 I still got the issue to connect particularly to Version 4 S3 but things are smooth with Hadoop-2.8. It's great that this profile takes care of every jar installation which otherwise is needed to be done manually.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.